# I need some help in correcting my codes in php - How to get the video id from a YouTube URL

Tags: php, google-api, youtube, youtube-api

I want to fetch youtube video id from the URL but YouTube has many different patterns for the URL. I am getting thumbnails from one of the patterns which is (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Wm6-8X3Vq4) but unable to get from this type of URL (https://youtu.be/HCjNJDNzw8Y) and this is my code. And I want this code should work for both of the URLs. Plz, Help!

```
if (isset($_POST["Submit"])) {
    $url = $_POST["url"];
    $value = explode('v=', $url);
    $videoId = $value[1];

} ?>
```

Comment: How many types of youtube video URL inserted into database?

Comment: Why not use the google apis php client library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that video ID is `11` chars length and can be preceded by `v=` or `vi=` or `v/` or `vi/` or `youtu.be/` So the simplest way to do this:-

**PHP Code:-**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["Submit"])){
    $url = $_POST["url"];
    preg_match_all("#(?<=v=|v\/|vi=|vi\/|youtu.be\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}#", $url, $matches);
echo $matches[0][0];

} 

?>
```

**HTML FORM:-**

```
<form method="post">

<input type="text" name="url"><br>

<input type="submit" name="Submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Thank You So Much. It is working now.

Comment: please mark as accepted answer , so other can use this code please.